# Using a .def in Visual Studio instead of dllimport/dllexport with global variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, dll

In the PluginLoader.exe's main.cpp:

```
int Lives = 9;
```

The project also contains a .def file that exports the Lives variable (mangled C++):

```
EXPORTS
?Lives@@3HA
```

Using dependency walker, I verified when opening PluginLoader.exe that `?Lives@@3HA` is indeed being exported. A .lib is also being exported which should contain the stubs that we can link against in other projects. Using dumpbin.exe on the stub PluginLoader.lib I get:

```
4 ?Lives@@3HA
1 __IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_PluginLoader
2 __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR
4 __imp_?Lives@@3HA
3 ⌂PluginLoader_NULL_THUNK_DATA
```

PluginLoader is loading a SimplePlugin.dll using LoadLibrary / GetProcAddress. SimplePlugin.dll has a main.cpp that looks like this:

```
extern int Lives;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void PluginMain()
{
  ++Lives;
}
```

SimplePlugin also links against the stub PluginLoader.lib. When trying to increment Lives, I always crash with an ACCESS VIOLATION. It would appear that my SimplePlugin.dll is pseudo getting its own version of the Lives variable, even though it linked against the stub.

If I change ONLY the SimplePlugin's Lives to:

```
__declspec(dllimport) extern int Lives;
```

Everything works as expected. Why is this? I thought the purpose of a .def was to not have to use dllexport/dllimport. My current hypothesis is that dllimport with a global variable is doing some trickery behind the scenes (how does `&Lives` work in the dll vs the exe?). Does this have something to do with the `__imp_?Lives@@3HA`?

Note: *Importing function pointers without dllimport works just fine. Its only with global variables that I get a crash. This reproduces in VS 2010 and 2012*

Sample project: https://db.tt/maV0oWop

Comment: A global variable cannot be safely exported, only a pointer to such a variable.  Required so the DLL can be relocated.  By using __declspec you tell the compiler to take care of that pointer for you without you having to do anything else.  Recommended of course.  Using accessor functions (Get/SetLives) is recommended as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler indeed generates indirection code when you use `dllimport` on data.

The reason is that a DLL can only export a pointer to the exported data and `dllimport` does the magic of dereferencing that pointer for you. That obviously is not required for function pointers.

[MS docs on that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/619w14ds.aspx)